# Visio Reverse Engineer Won't Add Data Source

Tags: sql, database-design, diagram, visio

I have Visio 2010 Premium, and I'm trying to connect to a SQL database.  I go to the Database tab, and choose Reverse Engineer.  If I choose Microsoft SQL Server, there are no data sources.  I choose New... and set up an ODBC connect to the server and database.  It is a successful test connection.  When I get back to the Reverse Engineer Wizard, it didn't add the new data source, and I can't go to Next.  It says "No valid data source is specified for connection. Specify a valid data source to proceed."  If I go to New... again and set it up again, it still won't add it.  I tried an ODBC connection, and OLE connection, nothing works to add the Data Source.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You haven't got an answer in two days. Guess you'll need to reformulate your question - that is - if you haven't solved your problem by yourself already. ;) I can't myself help - having no external DB at hand.

Comment: yeah, I can't remember which it is, but I had to choose the bottom option for a connection.  It was the system DSN, I believe.  When I chose that option and then added a data source, it added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use the ODBC generic data source

Try using the ODBC generic data source in order to have it appear in the Data sources list:

1. On the first page, select `Microsoft SQL Server` from the drop-down list:

[image: Select Installed Visio drivers]

2. Click Setup, then select `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`. Then, click OK:

[image: ODBC Driver]

3. Now select the `New...` button (right of `Data sources`) to create a new source.
4. Go through the `Create New Data Source` wizard (File/User/System doesn't really matter - it's just where the definition is stored), creating a new data source, making sure to select `ODBC Driver 17 fo SQL Server` *again* when prompted:

[image: Selection of driver]

The data source will then appear in the `Data sources` list.

---

---

---

---

Note: System DSNs may not be modified within Visio unless running as administrator. When not running as administrator, this message will be received:

[image: ODBC System DSN Warning]

To work around this, type 'ODBC' at the start menu, and edit the System DSN from the ODBC Data Sources tool (Visio is a 32-bit image, so use the 32-bit ODBC tool):

[image: ODBC tool]

It can also be accessed through: `%windir%\syswow64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using straight SQL server, instead of 17, but you were right. The generic ODBC works.  It gives you a warning, but it works anyway.

Comment: The thing hasn't been updated since 2008, even in Visio 2019, yet it still works well enough. What a mess!